# Pfsense - Installing Latest 'speedtest-cli' ( v2.1.3) to overcome error 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10'

Tags: bsd, pfsense

Anyone able to install the latest 'speedtest-cli'  ( v2.1.3) in their pfsense box to overcome error;

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Apparently something changed upstream and there has been a
v2.1.3 ( https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/pull/769 )
released to fix this bug ...

I tried ( as recommended at their main page ) in my pfsense 2.5.0 box ;

```
cd /usr/local/bin
curl -Lo speedtest-cli https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py
chmod +x speedtest-cli
```

But I only got the error below ;

```
env: python: No such file or directory
```

Note 1:   Current version  is  2.1.2  which is installed via

```
pkg install -y py37-speedtest-cli

   New packages to be INSTALLED:
   py37-speedtest-cli: 2.1.2 [pfSense]
```

Note 2:   Installing v 2.1.3 in an OpenSuse 15.x box is flawless

```
speedtest-cli --version

  speedtest-cli 2.1.3
  Python 2.7.17 (default, Jan 24 2020, 15:33:58) [GCC]
```

Note 3:   I am also unable to open a ticket at their github page to enquire further

```
  https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

For those with `pfsense` 2.5, I found this to work:

```
pkg install -y py38-speedtest-cli
```

Python version seems to have changed to 3.8.